# Upgrading from Azure MSAL to MSAL 2.0

Tags: azure, msal.js, msal-angular

Trying to upgrade from the @Azure/MSAL library to the latest v2 of MSAL.js 2.0 but getting the following error:

`Network request failed: If the browser threw a CORS error, check that the redirectUri is registered in the Azure App Portal as type 'SPA'`

Noticed that the `acquireTokenSilent()` method no longer takes a `logon_hint` as a parameter so switched to the `ssoSilent()` method instead and pass in a `SsoSilentRequest` with the `logon_hint` set. Still getting this error though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the error message was sort of obvious. Need to update the redirect URIs under Authentication for the App registration in Azure AD. There is a to migrate the URIs there from Web to Single-Page Application...

Looks like this change to the App registration is required for upgrading to the v2.0 version of the MSAL library. Ref the following warning in the Azure Portal:

`This app has implicit grant settings enabled. If you are using any of these URIs in a SPA with MSAL.js 2.0, you should migrate URIs.`